# Compile R Script to markdown

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

Using RStudio's "Compile Notebook to html" feature, I noticed that a temporary .md file was created in the process, but deleted automatically. At one point I was lucky enough to see its content, and it is exactly what I need: the code chunks alternate with output chunks, all perfectly formatted.

So my question is: how do I generate such an .md file directly form an R script?

Comment: maybe run `knitr::spin()` directly from the R console?

Comment: That's actually it. If you'd like, make it into an answer and I'll accept it as it's even more straightforward than eipi10's answer (which does work well too).

Comment: Update: After experimenting a bit in RStudio, knit::spin() will give fast and good results in many cases; however, the R markdown route (eipi10's solution) is definitely the way to go when dealing with non-ascii characters, which is daily in my case. So as it is more reliable I switched back to his answer as the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run "Knit to HTML", a markdown file is temporarily created and deleted. To keep the markdown file, add the following to the YAML code at the top of the RMD file.

```yaml
---
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

Here is a helpful reference: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#keeping-markdown

Answer (score 8):

You could also run `knitr::spin()` directly from the R console.